# Is GridFS via PHP useable if primary is unavailable?

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

#### Konfiguration

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.5.9
- MongoDB 3.0.2
- MongoDB PHP driver 1.6.6

#### Setup

I have a globally distributed MongoDB replica set (for testing purpose) with 3 servers. One has `priority = 1`, others have `priority = 0` so they will never become primary.
This setup is used to distribute files to the replicated servers by adding them directly on the primary server using GridFS. Distribution works fine. 
I have created a simple php watcher script which is executed on the secondary servers using read preference `\MongoClient::RP_NEAREST`. I wanted to determine the timestamp when the replicated received all files from the primary.

I wanted to make sure that the php script on the secondary servers are using the mongodb instance on their server (and not the primary), and therefore I stopped the primary mongodb server. After doing this, the two servers are keeping their secondary role.

#### Issue

If the primary server is unavailable, I was still able to execute queries like `count()` and `find()` on regular collections (also `fs.files` collection).
But calls that use GridFS will throw an `MongoConnectionException: No candidate servers found` exception.

#### Script

I have created a little script with which you should be able to reproduce the error.

```
$serverList = '...';

$conn   = new \MongoClient(
        'mongodb://'.$serverList,
        array(
            'replicaSet'        => 'r0',
            'readPreference'    => \MongoClient::RP_NEAREST,
            'username'          => 'bat',
            'password'          => '',
            'db'                => 'bat'
        )
    );

$db     = $conn->selectDB('bat');

echo 'works fine...';
$files          = $db->selectCollection('fs.files');
$documentsCount = $files->count();
$documents      = $files->find();
foreach($documents as $document) {
    echo $document['filename'] . ', ';
}

echo 'throws exception...';
$gridfs = $db->getGridFS();
$documentsCount = $gridfs->find()->count();
$documents  = $gridfs->find();
foreach($documents as $document) {
    echo $document->getFilename();
}
```

If the primary server is unavailable, the lines after `echo 'works fine...';` will work fine, while the line after `echo 'throws exception...';` will throw an exception.

Maybe this is related to an issue in the java driver [JAVA-401](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-401), there was a similar problem with usage of secondary servers and gridfs. Maybe the gridfs ist trying to *ensuring indices* if the fs.files collection contains less than 1000 files which is not possible on secondary.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, it was simply the incorrect line `$gridfs->find()->count()`. If you execute `$gridfs->count()` or  `$gridfs->find()` it works fine.

> So you'll have to use  `$gridfs->count()` instead of `$gridfs->find()->count()`.

I dont't know why `$gridfs->find()->count()` works correctly (and only correctly) if a primary server is available.

Comment: I know you set your read preference but the only time a cursor could not be made is if the read preference for some reason was not working, since $gridfs->count() does not use a cursor if no criteria is supplied if I remember right

Comment: Also `$gridfs->find()` works fine and result is useable, only `$gridfs->find()->count()` is causing an exception. Why should the second call use different cursor (or create the cursor in a different way) which may not be aware of the read preference setting? 
I would say that `$gridfs->find()->count()` should not execute queries in an other way than `$gridfs->find() `.

Comment: find() won't cause a cursor iteration remember